# MySQL update if record does not exists in other table

Tags: mysql, sql, conditional-statements

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to check if a specific record exists in table B. if so, don't update table A.

I have tried googling, but I only find the insert version and I'm not sure if it's even possible with an update query.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you figure this out? It would be useful to me!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
update table_to_update 
set some_column = 123
where id = 1
and id not in (select id from table_b)
```

Comment: I'm afraid it is not what is wanted. This query will update all records from table A which do not exist in table B. But John want to update specific record, so `id = some_value AND ` or some other condition must be added to `where` clause.

Comment: @Riateche You are correct, even though my question is a bit vague about it.

Comment: I wonder if there is a solution with a trigger or stored procedure? before update /* code here */

Answer (score 4):

> The following SQL statements function as a foreign key in where I add
>   a new field in the daughter table with the condition that this value
>   **does not** exist in a column of the master table.

```
UPDATE t1
SET c1 = ?
WHERE t1.id = ?
AND ? NOT IN (SELECT id FROM t2);
```

Meaning of the parameters and tables:

- t1: daughter table
- t2: master table
- 1st ? : Value that will be established in the field of t1.c1 if the condition is met
- 2nd ? : Identifier of the record where the field to be updated is located
- 3rd ? : Value necessary to evaluate the condition, where I compare it with the field of t2

**The value of the first and third parameters must be the same!**

*When using this statement, when we refer to the field of the master table, the column must have a primary key. That's why the similarity with the foreign key.*

---

The second alternative would also be:

```
UPDATE t1 a
LEFT JOIN t2 b
ON b.column = ?
SET t1.c1 = ?
WHERE b.column IS NULL && a.id = ?;
```

**The first and second parameters have to be the same**. Where `column` is a column of the master table.

*On the other hand, when using this other sentence we have more flexibility, since it is not a necessary condition that the column of the master table has a primary key.*

Comment: Please write your answer in English, since [Stack Overflow is an English site.](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676)

Answer (score 2):

You could also try with MySQL [exists](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) expression. Using exists syntax on older MySQL versions i.e. 5.0 proved for me to be faster than using nested query.

```
update table_a
set some_column = 'bla'
where not exists (select id
                        from table_b
                        where table_a.id = table_b.id)
```

Comment: This solution is highly inefficient and requires far more processing power than juergen d his solution.